# Making an HTML5 game framework for RPG games

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine

I really would like to know where to start when developing an HTML framework in general. I've made HTML5+javascript games with lime.js, but I'm confused on the actual makeup of HTML5 frameworks(i.e. lime.js, impact.js, etc.). My main question is "How could someone begin developing a HTML5+javascript game engine?".

Comment: Might I suggest asking on the [GameDev Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)? (you may get more relevant answers there.) Anyway, the general advice given to people who want to "write an engine" seems to be to make a bunch of games first, and then extract out the common components into an engine ;)

Comment: Thanks, I will consider asking gamedev Stack Exchange.

Comment: Or use an existing one to learn from: [RPG JS: Your online RPG on your browser](http://rpgjs.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Kinect.js framework? http://www.kineticjs.com/

There seems to be quite a few 2D games created with it. There is also three.js for 3D canvas stuff. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/webgl/part-3-html5-canvas-webgl-with-three-js/

You can base your framework on these libraries or use them as a reference.